# Can I try SQL Server BIG Data Cluster for free?

Tags: sql-server, clustering, azure, big-data

I can not find information about test SQL Server Big Data Cluster in a development environment. We have some AKSes and would like to try installing SQL Server Big Data Cluster.

Is it possible to do it for free?
Can the master instance be SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition?

Comment: check out here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19Y6g7NtFk8

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure but as I understand he is talking about SQL Server BIG Data Cluster for production environment. We would like to check If this technology is for us and not sure If is free option for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Microsoft documentation, under [SQL Server Editions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-version-15?view=sql-server-ver15#-editions):

> SQL Server Developer edition lets developers build any kind of
> application on top of SQL Server. It includes all the functionality of
> Enterprise edition, but is licensed for use as a development and test
> system, not as a production server. SQL Server Developer is an ideal
> choice for people who build and test applications.

SQL Server Developer Edition supports all the same functionality that Enterprise Edition does, which is supported as a [master instance for a big data cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-version-15?view=sql-server-ver15#RDBMSM).

According to [deployment guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/big-data-cluster/deployment-guidance?view=sql-server-ver15#sql-server-editions) from Microsoft, Developer Edition is the default deployed edition for a Big Data Cluster, and you upgrade to Enterprise for production systems after initial deployment:

> Big Data Cluster edition is determined by the edition of SQL Server
> master instance. At deployment time Developer edition is deployed by
> default. You can change the edition after deployment. See Configure
> SQL Server master instance.

Comment: Thank you for that. So I understand that default option of installation of SQL Server Big Data Cluster on AKSes is free (only payment for azure machines).

Comment: could you advice ?:)

Comment: @grochu licensing/costing advice is generally outside the scope of dba.se as there are obviously financial impacts to licensing and cloud resourcing so any questions should be taken to your licensing reseller or CSP. What I can say is that SQL Server Developer Edition does not incur a cost, however, you will need to pay for any compute resources required to run the instance(s), whether this is standalone VMs, AKS or some other option. You may also have to pay for OS licenses depending on the OS and your licensing agreement. Again, check this with your licensing reseller, CSP or your admins.

Comment: Thank you for information